# C# Google Sheets API get the Row of a certain Value

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets V4 API, everything I used it for works perfectly fine, but I didn't find a way to enter a value and get the row where that value is, basically searching for it if you get what I mean. Is it even possible? Or is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161249/google-sheets-api-how-to-find-a-row-by-value-and-update-its-content

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no endpoint in the API that supports this functionality.

As a workaround, you can:

1. Obtain all the data in the Sheet and iterate over it, until you find the value. This method, if the Sheet is large, can take quite a while - and the bandwidth consumption can be considerably large.
2. Inject a [`=MATCH()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function call that searches throughout all the Sheet. Afterwards, simply retrieve the value computed by it. In this case, the bandwidth will be lower - although the method may take more time overall since more requests are involved. You can learn more about this option in this Stackoverflow question: [Google Sheets API: How to find a row by value and update it's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161249/google-sheets-api-how-to-find-a-row-by-value-and-update-its-content)